# C# - display cents (US), pennies (GB) of money value

Tags: c#, culture, currency-formatting

I want to show culture specific currency representation of a digit value if it is under certain amount. For example:

```
 double money = 0.3;
 var currency = money.ToString("C", "en-US")
 var currency2 = money.ToString("C", "en-GB")
```

shows `$0.30` for US and `£0.30` for UK (en-GB).

Is there any way to represent them as `30¢` for US and `30p` for UK? I also want to support other cultures in similar way if possible.

Comment: Custom formatter will do it

Comment: @pm100 you mean I need to write a mapper that processes monetary unit's to different cultures?

Comment: Neither `NumberFormatInfo`, nor `RegionInfo` provide cent symbol (`¢`), so it seems custom formatter is required